# Wrapping an existing node cli tool in a GitHub action

Tags: node.js, github, command-line-interface, github-actions, building-github-actions

I'm still figuring out creating a custom GitHub Action and have a question.

#### How I use the node CLI tool

I install the npm package in my repo.
I add a build script in the package json file, e.g. `"build": "clitool --foo bar"`
This cli tool is able to fetch the files from my repo directory.

#### What I want to do

I want to build a GitHub Actions wrapper for this cli tool so it's distributable.
Ideally, users would use this Action in their yaml file, supply the parameters which will get based to my custom action and then somehow passed to the build script e.g. `"build": "clitool --foo ${passed_from_users_action_yaml_file}"`

From the custom GitHub Action that I'm building, can I execute the build script like I did if it was my own repo? As in have the entry point as the custom yaml, but then pass the execution to the package json?